# How to change visual appearance of ANSI colors for *shell* buffers running on "GUI Emacs"?

Tags: colors, ansi

**OS:** Linux 4.19.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
**Emacs:** GNU Emacs 28.0.50, with a solarized theme from [here](https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized)
**Terminal emulator:** terminator 1.91, with a solarized (dark) palette

---

The displays below were done by running the following bash script within a `*shell*` buffer (i.e. a buffer started with `M-x shell`):

```
echo -e '\e[30m██\e[31m██\e[32m██\e[33m██\e[34m██\e[35m██\e[36m██\e[37m██\e[0m'
```

"No-window"/"non-GUI" (`-nw`) Emacs process, running on a terminator 1.91 terminal emulator:
[image]

"GUI Emacs" process:

[image]

How can I make ANSI colors in the GUI Emacs environment look like those in the "non-GUI" environment?

**NB:** I do *not* want to modify my terminal emulator in any way.  I am happy with it.  I want to modify *GUI Emacs* so that it produces the same behavior as my terminal emulator does.

---

For what it's worth, below are the first 8 colors in the output for `(list-colors-display`) running on "non-GUI" Emacs, which correspond to the colors I get from the ANSI color test shown above:

[image]

The colors with the same names (as reported by `(list-colors-display)` in "GUI-Emacs" are shown below; again, they match the colors from the ANSI colors test shown earlier:

[image]

In light of this, it occurs to me that maybe a way to achieve what I want is to redefine the colors `black`, `red`, ..., `white`?  How would I do this?

Is there a "better" ("higher-level", more robust, etc.) way to solve this problem?

---

EDIT: The accepted answer in [#000000 and true black in terminal Emacs colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/36219/882) shows that its OP's issue was due to his gnome-terminal configuration.  My question, on the other hand, has nothing to do with gnome-terminal, or with terminal emulators in general.  *It's about GUI Emacs.*  The one other answer to https://emacs.stackexchange.com proposes to modify the `default` font.  This will *not* solve my problem.  Changing the `default` font would affect at most one foreground color.  I have a problem with 8 colors.  Also, the text that exhibits these various colors often have the same face (e.g. `comint-highlight-prompt`).

EDIT:

I changed the code for the ANSI color test to this:

```
echo -e '\e[30m██\e[31m██\e[32m██\e[33m██\e[34m██\e[35m██\e[36m██\e[37m██\e[0m'
echo -e '\e[30mXX\e[31mXX\e[32mXX\e[33mXX\e[34mXX\e[35mXX\e[36mXX\e[37mXX\e[0m'
```

Now, the output (on "GUI Emacs") is this:

[image]

**The key point is this:** According to `describe-face`, *all* those X's have the `default` face.  These means that ***no solution based on modifying *faces* will solve this problem***.

---

**EDIT:**  First I ran this:

```lisp
;; just to get a response...
(setq ansi-color-names-vector
  ["red3" "red3" "red3" "red3" "red3" "red3" "red3" "red3"])

(ansi-color-make-color-map) ;; is this necessary???
```

Then I started a fresh `*shell*` buffer (`M-x shell`), and ran the ANSI color test shown above, namely:

```
echo -e '\e[30m██\e[31m██\e[32m██\e[33m██\e[34m██\e[35m██\e[36m██\e[37m██\e[0m'
echo -e '\e[30mXX\e[31mXX\e[32mXX\e[33mXX\e[34mXX\e[35mXX\e[36mXX\e[37mXX\e[0m'
```

I got the same results I got earlier.  In particular, the 8 colors were different, even though all 8 entries in `ansi-color-names-vector` are the same.

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#000000 and true black in terminal Emacs colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36219/000000-and-true-black-in-terminal-emacs-colors)

Comment: @Tyler I don't see any connection.

Comment: I think you need to customize `ansi-color-names-vector`.

Comment: See also `ansi-color-faces-vector`

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' the connection is that colors in terminal emacs and gui emacs don't necessarily match; it depends on the color profile of the terminal. I'm not sure how to set the terminator color profile, but for gnome-terminal there's an option in the tool bar that solved an issue very similar to this (i.e., colors in terminal differed from those in gui)

Comment: @Tyler: I ***don't*** want to change what my terminal emulator is doing.  I want to change what GUI emacs is doing.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': No matter how I change `ansi-color-names-vector` I see no difference.  I even changed it so that all its elements are `"red1"`, and then ran `(ansi-color-make-color-map)`, but I still get the same colors when I run the 8-color test shown above.  Do I need to do anything else to get the new definition of `ansi-color-names-vector` to have an effect?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were trying to get the colors the same in GUI and terminal, when you really wanted to change the GUI to match customizations you have applied to the terminal.

Comment: Changing ansi-color-names-vector doesn't change list-colors-display for me, but it does change the output in shell-mode. Did you try re-running your echo command after changing ansi-color-names-vector?

Comment: @Tyler: I did, but maybe I did something wrong?  I'll edit my post to spell out exactly what I did.  It'll be a few minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128274/discussion-between-tyler-and-kjo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some exploring, we determined that @Gilles suggestion of modifying `ansi-color-names-vector` was the correct approach. It can't be set with a regular `setq`, it needs to be updated through the `Customize` interface (i.e., `M-x customize-variable ansi-color-names-vector`. Changing the value won't change existing text in the shell terminal, but new text added after the update will take the new colors.

If you do want to set it from code, you need to do this:

```lisp
(setq ansi-color-names-vector
      ["red3" "red3" "red3" "red3" "red3" "red3" "red3" "red3"])

(ansi-color-map-update 'ansi-color-names-vector ansi-color-names-vector)
```

Comment: Thank you!  BTW, how did you figure out that the call to `ansi-color-map-update` was necessary?  (I had been using `ansi-color-make-color-map` instead, which was useless.)

Comment: the defcustom form for ansi-color-names-vector has a :set argument of ansi-color-map-update; that's the function that gets called whenever the variable is changed via customize.

Comment: That's *very* good to know.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Please note ansi color names vector was made obsolete.  You have to customize faces `ansi-color-COLOR_NAME` eg. `ansi-color-red`, `ansi-color-yellow`, etc.