# Wrong colors on Xfce-terminal

Tags: terminal-emacs, themes, colors

I use a colour scheme called solarized.  Since I updated my Debian system a couple of weeks ago, colours are all wrong when I run emacs on Xfce-terminal

[image]

Unsetting the COLORTERM environment variable appears to fix the issue.

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

`COLORTERM` is set to `truecolor`, while `TERM` is set to `xterm-256color`.

EDIT: It appears that the 16 ANSI colours inside Emacs do not match the colours from the terminal palette.  For example, "red" is shown as #cd0000 inside Emacs, whereas in the terminal palette it's defined as #df322f

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#000000 and true black in terminal Emacs colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36219/000000-and-true-black-in-terminal-emacs-colors)

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the color settings for Xfce-terminal, see the linked question for a similar problem

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. I've added more info.